# Pet slept on keyboard, weird colors in IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Please stop laughing. My cat slept on my keyboard. When I came back I wonder what these colors are:

[image]

I like to get rid of them but I don't know how to remove them.

1. Close and reopen of the file does not work.
2. Close and reopen of the project does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: Option 1: Window > Preferences > Reset Perspective - Option 2: Put the cat back on the keyboard and hope he undoes it.

Comment: I would prefer the second solution, for science...

Comment: Such ignorance here is unbelievable. If you check the API, you'll see that you'll need to place a *dog* on the keyboard to undo the workings of the cat. Please read the API before posting nonsense folks.

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.eclemma.doc%2Fpages%2Fannotations.html

Comment: [How to Make Homemade Cat Repellent](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Homemade-Cat-Repellent)

Comment: Pair programming :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Undocumented in the API, it's quite clear in the source that you use a *mouse*.

Comment: I recommend [this instructional manual](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Oi-Cat-Frog-Friends/dp/1444932527/ref=asc_df_1444932527/) to avoid such problems in the future.

Comment: This question is a duplicate? Are you out of your minds? This is an original.

Comment: @forpas I do not think this is an duplicate either because: my markers where compleatly green and the question marked for duplicate seems compleatly red. Also I do not know what to do to reset to the feature my cat did, so I can not tell if anyone of my markers where red!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upvote for the cutest question ever.

Regarding the colors: Reminds me of visualization of test coverage with [EclEmma](https://www.eclemma.org/), which shows its results with coloured markers for fully (green), partly (yellow) or not (red) covered source code.

You can get rid of the coloured markers by deleting the coverage results by clicking the single or double grey "x" in the coverage view like shown at the bottom of the following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this here for reference purposes from the Eclipse [code coverage FAQs](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.eclemma.doc%2Fpages%2Fannotations.html).

> **How can I remove the coverage coloring from the Java editors again?** 
> If you remove the coverage session, also the coverage
>   coloring will disappear. For this, hit Remove Session or Remove All
>   Sessions in the Coverage view's toolbar.

From [Using the coverage view](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.eclemma.doc%2Fpages%2Fcoverageview.html)

> The Coverage view automatically appears when a new coverage session is
>   added or can manually opened from the `Window → Show View` menu in the
>   Java category. It shows coverage summaries for the active session.

[image]